# Run Error With Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

I just downloaded and installed Qt Creator.
I have not messed with the PATH or any other settings.
But when I try to run a Qt GUI Application project, it gives the following error:

```
cc1plus.exe:-1: error: error: unrecognized command line option "-fno-keep-inline-dllexport"
```

The output says:

> Error while building/deploying project ProjectFirst (kit: Desktop Qt
>   5.0.1 MinGW 32bit) When executing step 'Make'

I don't understand why this is happening. I looked it up online a lot before asking, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: remove other GCC from your Path, and you're done.

Answer (score 7):

I've just found the problem on my friend's computer the same as yours.

Type g++ --version to see what g++ is taking by default from your path.
If it is 4.4.* (<= 4.7.2) then found that old g++ and remove it to the trash.
Usually it goes with Perl package, needed by Qt configure.

Then return to Console and try g++ --version again
if it not 4.7.2 then lookfor old g++ again and remove it.

If it is written g++ : command not found or something like that - change your PATH variable.
Don't forget to reboot your computer after changing it.

When you got g++ --version with 4.7.2, look forward to having success.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use nmake, not mingw32-make

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the wrong mingw32 installation (an older version).

In order to solve this, check that the Kit you use has detected the correct Mingw version (this should be 4.7, which is located inside the qt installation tools directory).